# Web service, tomcat

Tags: web-services, tomcat, netbeans

I created a web service in my application, and when I want to test the methods of the web service I get this error:

[image]

I don't know what to do, I am a begginer in Java so any help would be great. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your xml tag looks like it's not closed.

If new, follow step by step in tutorials like these:
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/

Comment: Yea I know that my xml tag is not closed, but i don't know where that file is. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong I followed those steps and everything is created fine without problems, just when I want to test it, it shows me that error.